# C# 2010 - Download File From Sharepoint Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, ssis

I was wondering if you could help me with this, I'm a beginner, I'm trying to use "Script Task" at a SSIS project that should download a file from a sharepoint and save it at a local folder:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration.Assemblies;
using System.IO;

namespace ST_3b90f3dd23cf4b25bb1e0175ac566fde.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

    #region VSTA generated code
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion


    public void Main()
    {
        System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        string urlOfTheSPFile = "https://sharepointlocation";
        string localPathToTheFile = @"C:\localfolder";
        client.DownloadFile(urlOfTheSPFile, localPathToTheFile);
        client.Dispose();

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
}
```

This seemed to work fine at Visual Studio 2008 but now I'm using VS 2010 (C# 2010) and I cannot get it running.

Hope you can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @ before the remotepath and try using client rather than having to dispose.

```
  var remotefile = @"https://pathtoremotefile";
    var localfile = @"C:\pathtolocalfile";
    using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        // or new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","pass","domain");
        wc.DownloadFile(remotefile,localfile);
    }
```